# Solr do not split JSON

Tags: json, indexing, solr, split, lucene

I'm using Solr v8.0.0 and im trying to split a json at the indexing time using the method described at the [solr official documentation about Transforming JSON](https://lucene.apache.org/solr/guide/8_0/transforming-and-indexing-custom-json.html#mapping-parameters), but it is not working as expected, and I'm getting flat jsons at the end.

Here is how I'm doing it:

First I create a single core named C2

```
bin/solr create_core -c c2
```

Then, it's solrconfig.xml is automatically created and left as default.

then I try to index some data using the example URL. the only difference is that I added a ?commit=true to the end of the URL so we can see whats happening

```sh
curl 'http://localhost:8983/solr/c2/update/json/docs'\
'?commit=true'\
'?split=/'\
'&f=first:/first'\
'&f=last:/last'\
'&f=grade:/grade'\
'&f=subject:/exams/subject'\
'&f=test:/exams/test'\
'&f=marks:/exams/marks'\
 -H 'Content-type:application/json' -d '
{
  "first": "John",
  "last": "Doe",
  "grade": 8,
  "exams": [
    {
      "subject": "Maths",
      "test"   : "term1",
      "marks"  : 90},
    {
      "subject": "Biology",
      "test"   : "term1",
      "marks"  : 86}
  ]
}'
```

but at the end, I got this kind of indexing, and not the one that was shown in the example:

What I Got:

```json
{
      {
        "first":["John"],
        "last":["Doe"],
        "grade":[8],
        "subject":["Maths",
          "Biology"],
        "test":["term1",
          "term1"],
        "marks":[90,
          86],
        "id":"284878be-1339-43b5-8a1e-adb7a4be95fb",
        "_version_":1664059760532520960}]
  }
```

What I was supposed to get:

```json
{
  "first":"John",
  "last":"Doe",
  "marks":90,
  "test":"term1",
  "subject":"Maths",
  "grade":8
}
{
  "first":"John",
  "last":"Doe",
  "marks":86,
  "test":"term1",
  "subject":"Biology",
  "grade":8
}
```

My fields where flatten as it would usually do in a normal indexation, without the `?split=/` command in the url. Can anyone help me figure out why this behavior is happening?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, that's not the only difference. In your request you have:

```
'?split=/'\
```

In the example from the manual it is:

```
'?split=/exams'\
```

And since you're not splitting on `/exams` in your request, the result differs.